# how to give an error message when the login is failed using selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium web driver for automation tests. I want to give an error message in console of eclipse when the login fails. How to do this?

Here is my code

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("a@hotmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("123");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_b")).click();
```

Comment: Kindly explain your question more, By Adding code & logs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Find any logical attribute which can validate for you.

For an example genarlly login page title and page after login moves i.e. homepage or dashboard will be having different title.

so check like:

```
    String title = driver.getTitle();

    if(title.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Page")) {
        Assert.fail("Login Fail");

    }else if(title.equalsIgnoreCase("Dashbaord Page")){
        System.out.println("Login successful");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Page redirect to "+title);
    }
```

Comment: `Assert.assertEquals(true, false, ...)` seriously?!?! Why not just `Assert.fail(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Error message while doing Web Automation Testing can be done from Assertions. We need to assert if an element or any reference of Home Page is present or is appearing.

```
public void checkIfElementIsPresent(){

    WebElement elementToCheck = "locator of the element"
    int i=0;

    try{
        elementToCheck.isDisplayed
        System.out.println("Element Found !!!");
        i++;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.println("Element is not present");
        Assert.assertFalse("Login is not successful as the required element is not present", i==0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is NOT the proper way to use asserts. You are using the assert just to write a message to the log. Instead you should be asserting true for `elementToCheck.isDisplayed` without the `try-catch`. ... and why is the counter `i` in there? It's doing nothing.